# tense agreement about truth

Tags: grammar

For example, "I found that LA is not an island." (Truth always)

or "I ensured them that car insurance is necessary." (Truth in past and now still)

Do I have to use "was" instead of "is" for tense agreement?

Comment: No. There is no obligatory "tense agreement" in English. In both examples either _is_ or _was_ may be used, at the speaker's option. However, in the second example, the verb to use is _assured_. Not _ensured_, which does not take an indirect object and is therefore ungrammatical in this sentence, and doesn't mean what you want anyway (_to ensure_ means to find out for sure, not to tell anybody anything).

Comment: I seem to remember some forecasting about a quake eventually tearing part of California off the mainland.  So the "truth always" status of "LA is not an island" is somewhat debatable.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is still necessary, most people would default to `is`, but `was` is also correct because at the time it `was` necessary.  The fact that it is still necessary isn't necessarily relevant.  It depends on subtle context of the conversation.

Comment: What do you mean, "technically"? Exactly what rule is being applied to produce this judgement?

Comment: '...technically _was_ is correct...' assumes that there **is** an obligatory "tense agreement" in English, which J Lawler said/says there isn't. As both _was necessary_ and _is necessary_ (at the time the speaker utters the words) make sense, tecnically _both_ are correct here. And if the laws of the land have changed, one may be grammatically correct but a false statement.

Comment: @JohnLawler: It's technically correct because although people would usually default to *is*, *was* is still correct.  I'm judging that based on the fact that there isn't a rule to my knowledge that invalidates the usage of *was*.

Comment: @Jacobm001: Sorry if my downvote seems a bit harsh! But I'm solidly behind John & Edwin here, and it seems to me your *"technically **was** is correct"* erroneously implies that *"technically **is** is **incorrect**"*. And that bothers me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I have reworded for better clarification.

Comment: @Jacobm001: Downvote duly reversed, since I *do* agree with you that although in a general sense both tenses are "correct", certain contexts favour either past or present tense for conditions that are still (or "universally") true. But those contexts probably never actually *require* either tense, so I'm more than happy with your *"most people would..."* And let's not forget that OP could just as well have said *"I assured them that car insurance **would be** necessary."*